# Get city and street name for a link from PDE

Tags: here-api

In the project I am working on, I need to get the address of a link(street, city, postcode, country) for links returned from RME.

For the postcode and country, I can get the tileXY and level from index resource, and then use the ROAD_ADMIN_FC3 layer from the tile resource. But I couldnt find a way to find city and street.

How can I get the city and street name of a link from PDE while having only the link ID?

Note: I prefer not to use the routing api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Layer ROAD_GEOM_FC3 should give you the road name and ROAD_ADMIN_FC3 contains ADMIN_PLACE_IDS, this along with ADMIN_PLACE_1, ADMIN_PLACE_2 should give you city details.

Comment: thanks for your answer. How would I use the ADMIN_PLACE_IDS? How should I get the tile for the ADMIN_PLACE_n request?

Comment: Depending on the country get required ADMIN_PLACE_IDS from  ROAD_ADMIN_FC3 e.g for Europe i think ADMIN_PLACE_8 should give city. Then pass ID to index to get tilex tily     http://tcs.it.here.com/http-proxy2/PlatformDataExtension/doc-indexes.html?region=EU&release=2014Q3&urlroot=http://pde.api.here.com/1/ , Then use the layer ADMIN_PLACE_8 to get the Name.